# Create Simulation in R

Tags: r, simulation, probability, exponential

I have following problem:

A casualty insurance company has 1000 policyholders, each of whom will
independently present a claim in the next month with probability 5%.
Assuming that the amounts of the claims made are independent exponential
random variables with mean 800 Dollars.

Does anyone know how to create simulation in R to estimate the probability
that the sum of those claims exceeds 50,000 Dollars?

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Do you know about functions like `runif` and `rexp`?

Comment: Of course. What part is tripping you up

Comment: I have no idea at all where should I start with. Yeah, I know those functions @GregorThomas

Comment: I actually don't know the main problem of the question, but I do know several functions for generating random variables @Dason

Comment: @Alynn unfortunately SO isn't a good place if you don't know where to start. It is designed for specific questions and answers rather than requests for general tutorials on topics. Can you ask your professor for more details on where you are stuck?

Comment: You should start with simulating a single month. 1000 policy holders, each with 5% probability of making a claim. Use `rbinom` or `runif` to generate how many claims there are in a month using those parameters...

Comment: Oh, okay, I'll try that. Thank you so much @GregorThomas

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I thought SO is a place where we can ask anything that related to programming. Thank you for the information, I'll keep that in mind @user438383

Comment: @Alynn no need to apologise. SO is a place to ask specific questions about programming. When you figure out where to start, you are more than welcome to come back and ask any specific question about your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a homework assignment, so it's probably best to consult with your teacher(s) if you're unsure about how to approach this. Bearing that in mind, here's how I'd go about simulating this:

First, create a function that generates values from an exponential distribution and sums those values, based on the values you give in your problem description.

```
get_sum_claims <- function(n_policies, prob_claim, mean_claim) {
  sum(rexp(n = n_policies*prob_claim, rate = 1/mean_claim))
}
```

Next, make this function return the sum of all claims lots of times, and store the results. The line with `map_dbl` does this, essentially instructing R to return 100000 simulated sums of claims from the `get_sum_claims` function.

```
library(tidyverse)

claim_sums <- map_dbl(1:100000, ~ get_sum_claims(1000, 0.05, 800))
```

Finally, we can calculate the probability that the sum of claims is greater than 50000 by using the code below:

```
sum(claim_sums > 50000)/length(claim_sums)
```

This gives a fairly reliable estimate of ~ 0.046 as the probability that the sum of claims exceeds 50000 in a given month.

Comment: Yeah, it's indeed a homework assignment and my lecturer said to try it myself, but unfortunately I have no idea at all how to do it. Thank you so much for the very detailed explanation, I'll study that.

Comment: @Alynn I see, no worries. If there's anything else I can add to my answer that might help then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit inexperienced with R, but here is my solution.

First, construct a function which simulates a single trial. To do so, one needs to determine how many claims are filed **n**. I hope it is clear that **n** ~ Binomial(1000, 0.05). Note that, you cannot simply assume **n** = 1000 * 0.05 = 50. By doing so, you would decrease the variance, which will result in a lower probability. I can explain why this is the case if needed. Then, generate and sum **n** values based on an exponential distribution with mean 800.

```
simulate_total_claims <- function(){
claim_amounts <- rexp(rbinom(n=1,size=1000, prob = 0.05), rate = 1/800)
total <- sum(claim_amounts)
return(total)
}
```

Now, all that needs to be done is run the above function a lot and determine the proportion of runs which have values greater than 50000.

```
totals <- rerun(.n = 100000, simulate_total_claims())
estimated_prob <- mean(unlist(totals) > 50000)
```